# Wordpress plugins not updating/installing

Tags: wordpress

Since yesterday, I've tried numerous times to upgrade/install plugins on a website built with wordpress (not mine, first time I'm on it).

I get the following message while installing a new plugin:

```
Downloading install package from http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/[plugin-name].zip…

Unpacking the package…
```

And it stops there.

I tried updating akismet too. It didn't upgrade and the webite hanged into maintenance mode. The website is up again now and I get this message on my dashboard:

```
An automated WordPress update has failed to complete - please attempt the update again now.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Here are a few possibilities

- Incorrect permissions.
- Prombelmatic plugin.
- Configuration in .htaccess not allowing files large enough to perform the action.
- try adding **AddType x-mapp-php5 .php** to the top of your .htaccess file.
- Try deleting the .maintenance file.

  ---

Comment: The issue is that the download part is actually occuring, and the hand occurs when unpacking. So, I guess the permissions are set right.

Also, the server is already running PHP v5.2.11

Comment: The `AddType x-mapp-php5 .php` you mentionned is applicable only to 1and1's hosting according to [this article](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/automatic-update-never-has-worked) whenever php5 is not activated.

This website is hosted privately, so I can't really answer you something that would be helpful to you.

Comment: That is helpful, it means it's not godaddys grid problem.

Comment: See if you can unpack the plugins by hand and install them.

Comment: I'll be reverting to FTP soon, when I get the logins, but unfortunately this will not fix the actual problem.

Comment: It can tell us if you're files are actually downloading, or if it just thinks so and that's why it's not able to unpack.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I'll verify that files have been downloaded? My `wp-content/upgrade/` directory is empty.

Comment: I'm really not sure where they install to. You'll have to search for it and see if it's there